# Ignore HashCode from @EqualsAndHashCode - Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

I want to set `@EqualsAndHashCode` to avoid verbal code in java. However I want to use default `hashCode` from Java.

Is it possible using some parameter?

Note: `@EqualsAndHashCode` belongs to [Lombok library](https://projectlombok.org/) who is very used in Java to avoid use getters, setters, constructor , etc.

Comment: In case you understand "hashCode from Java" the inherited `Object#hashCode`, then you'd do very wrong. Any `HashMap` using your object as key would break because of the inconsistency between `hashCode` and `equals`. What Lombok generates is pretty good and you'd better stick with it, unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is not possible. There are [good reasons why you should implement both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java). Lombok is doing you a favour by preventing you from doing that.

If want to override just one of them, you'll need to implement it yourself.